# div elements gets pushed down when it contains text. A peculiar behavior of inline-block

Tags: html, css

Why does the first element get pushed down when its child contains text? Why inline-block behaves like this?

[image]
And how can I allign divs side-by-side while allowing them to have children? I want the grey box to have a list of elements one on top of the other, while still having everything aligned like this(it works fine if boxes don't contain children):

[image]

[The example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/uwRwM/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/uwRwM/1/)

```
.box {
display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easy fix. Add `overflow:hidden`.

This will force the element to contain the text.

```
.box {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

[**Working jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/uwRwM/2/)

Alternatively, you can set `vertical-align:top`.

```
.box {
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

[**Working jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/uwRwM/4/)

The reason this is occurring, is because the default vertical alignment of an `inline-block` element is `baseline`. Thus the reason it was on the bottom.

Comment: Thanks it works fine now! But why does it behave like this? When you set background to the child you can see that it's inside even without overflow: hidden . Like in this example http://jsfiddle.net/uwRwM/3/

Comment: @JoshC OK, can't ask for more.